# how to postioned the text in the bottom center, and i want also the Colors.black.withOpacity color to cover the entire width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i'm new to flutter and i'm trying to position the container that contain the text exactly in the bottom center, and i want also the Colors.black.withOpacity to cover the entire width behind the text

```
body: ListView(
       children: <Widget>
       [
         Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
           child: Stack(

             children: <Widget>
                [
           Container
           (
             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),

             child: new Image
                (
                  image: new AssetImage('images/99.jpg'), 
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                )
                ),

            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 125,
              child: Container
              (
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),

                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),


                child: Text("The text", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0), textAlign: TextAlign.center,), 


                ),
            )
            ,      

                ],
                ),
         ), 

       ],
      ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NTEZ.jpg)

Comment: I believe that your images will not all have the same height, do you want the text to be in a fixed position or to always be at the bottom of the image following the variation in height of the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to do a MediaQuery and store the size. You can do this right at the beginning off your build() method.

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
```

Then replace your Positioned widget with this.

```
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      width: size.width,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
        child: Text(
          "The text",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

This should work.